# What are these 2 files in the CenterNet MobileNetV2 from the Tensorflow OD model zoo?, Do we need them?

Tags: tensorflow, object, deep-learning, detection

[Do we need these files?, The Tensorflow Doc don't say anything about them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOevp.png)

Comment: Hi, could you put the image directly in the question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `model.tflite` file is the pretrained model in `.tflite` format. So if you want to use the model out of the box, you can use this file.

The `label_map.txt` is used to map the output of your network to actual comprehensible results. I.e. both of the files are needed if you want to use the model out of the box. It is not needed for re-training.